# changing line of text if the text increases the width of the cell in fpdf php?

Tags: php, cell, fpdf

i am trying to generate a pdf in php via fpdf, the table is populated with data from the database but the length of the text is more than the width of the cell, so how to change line of the text if the length of the text increases the width of the cell?
here is the code

```
$this->Cell(20, 6, $field, 1, 0, 'L', true);
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try

The MultiCell is used for print text with multiple lines. It has the same atributes of Cell except for ln and link.

`$pdf->MultiCell( 200, 40, $field, 1)`;

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

this is helpful but the problem with multicell is that it is printing the cell vertically and not horizontally.